# Reorder denormalized column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a denormalized table that contains up to 8 user photos:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
  Id int NOT NULL,
  ProfileId int NOT NULL,
  Photo1 int DEFAULT NULL,
  Photo2 int DEFAULT NULL,
  Photo3 int DEFAULT NULL,
  Photo4 int DEFAULT NULL,
  Photo5 int DEFAULT NULL,
  Photo6 int DEFAULT NULL,
  Photo7 int DEFAULT NULL,
  Photo8 int DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Users_ProfileId_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProfileId], [Id])
)
```

A user can change the position of each photo (move it). What I would like to achieve is that when user moves a photo to another position, this photo must be saved to a different Photo-column and the rest of photos must be reordered:

If I move Photo8 to Photo1, it should save Photo8 to Photo1, Photo1 to Photo2, Photo2 to Photo3 ...

And if I move Photo2 to Photo4, it should save Photo2 to Photo4, Photo3 to Photo2, Photo4 to Photo3.

How can I achieve this with SQL and preferably without dynamic-generated SQL (EXEC-Method).

Comment: That is a terrible DB design. Would you consider changing it?

Comment: think 'linked list' and make a couple new tables to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You should consider changing your DB design. For instance:

```
users table
-----------
id           int
profile_id   int
name         varchar
....


photos table
------------
id        int
user_id   int
rank      int
```

Then a user can have as many photos as he/she likes and you only need to change the rank to change the order of the photos.

This would then set photo 8 to 1 and the others will be reordered:

```
update photos
set rank = case when rank = 8 then 1
                when rank between 1 and 7 then rank + 1
                else rank
           end
where user_id = 1
```

A thunb rule for DB design is when you need numbers in your column names (like photo1, photo2) then it is bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you do not want to change the DB. Consider solving this in the application code like this:

1. Copy the PhotoIDs to a List (with up to 8 items obviously)
2. Insert/delete/reorder as you like (this is easy in most languages)
3. Copy the list contents back to the columns

Steps 1 and 3 are reusable so you only need to write them once.